# Получить и передать значение ползунка Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

В библиотеке Jquery UI есть объект Slider:

```
$("#slider").slider();
```

Допустим, мне нужно получить какое-то значение ползунка и передать это значение в css свойство другого объекта:

```
$(".player1").css("opacity", x);
```

где `x` - значение ползунка в данный момент.

Как это реализовать при помощи методов `.slider`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На этой странице вы можете найти документацию для jQuery UI Slider:

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

Для получения позиции `handler`'ов вы можете воспользоваться `event`'ом `change` или методом `value` (или `values` для нескольких значений).

Использование `change`:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
    change: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Таким образом вы будете получать текущие значения слайдера при **их изменении изменении**.

Метод же, в свою очередь, удобен для получения текущего состояния слайдера в неопределенный (не связанный с изменением) момент времени:

```
var selection = $( ".selector" ).slider( "value" );
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не сразу понял что параметры нужно объявлять внутри функции.

Comment: P.S. Используя 'slide:' вместо 'change:' получаем изменения и в процессе изменения состояния слайдера